# Generate 1 bit depth BMP image

Tags: image, go, bitmap, bmp

I need to create a mono bitmap image with a colour depth of 1 bit, for example:

```
$ file exampleMono.bmp 
> exampleMono.bmp: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 640 x 1000 x 1
```

In Go, I'm able to generate a simple bmp image with the following:

```
tempPal := color.Palette([]color.Color{
    color.Black, color.White,
})
img := image.NewPaletted(image.Rect(640, 1000,0,0), tempPal)
filename := fmt.Sprintf("img-%d.bmp", time.Now().Unix())
file, _ := os.Create(filename)
bmp.Encode(file, img)
file.close
```

However, the resulting bmp file has a colour depth of 8-bits.

```
$ file img-1611574755.bmp 
> img-1611574755.bmp: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 640 x 1000 x 8
```

I've had a look through the bmp, image and draw packages in Go and haven't found anything that appears to provide the ability to set the colour depth to 1 bit. Is it possible to achieve what I need in Go and if so, how?

Comment: Just FYI, if you want to generate any such things for testing, you can use **ImageMagick** in the Terminal, e.g. `magick -size 64x48 gradient: -type bilevel image.bmp`

Comment: Or if you want to convert a PNG or JPEG into one, `magick input.png -type bilevel output.bmp`

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from [here](https://github.com/golang/image/blob/35266b937fa69456d24ed72a04d75eb6857f7d52/bmp/writer.go#L181) down; `golang.org/x/image/bmp`'s `Encode()` does not support `bpp=1` in any of image modes.

It should be easy to take pieces from `Encode()` and write your own one-purpose encoding function as BMP file format and all its variants are well documented. BMP file format specs: on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_format) or [FileFormat](https://docs.fileformat.com/image/bmp/).